# Window Post Message on Opener not working in Edge

Tags: javascript, window, microsoft-edge, postmessage

Fiddling with Edge Extension and I came across the Issue.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open "w3schools.com". Add a message listener on the page.
2. Click "Try Yourself" button on the page. A page opens up.
3. Perform a "window.opener.postMessage" on new tab.

The message send to opener is not obtained by the message listener added on the Main Page.
(Works on Chrome/Firefox)

window.postMessage on same tab is working. Could anyone give the possible reason for this issue?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `window.origin`, change it to `window.location.origin`. It worked for me.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I would like to perform a postMessage on the opener from the opened page. Ex: window.opener.postMessage("random", "*") || window.location.origin returns a string, whats the use of that?